# Why do almost all Woody Allen movies contain the same font style?

Tags: film-techniques, woody-allen

Why do almost all Woody Allen movies contain the same font style of opening and closing credits?

I've watched *Blue Jasmine*, *Match Point* and *Vicky Cristina Barcelona*. All 3 movies contain the same font style of opening and closing credits.

Comment: Note that Wes Anderson also uses the same font for all of his title text, in general.

Comment: Three movies is hardly "almost all" when it comes to Woody Allen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font is *EF WINDSOR Elongated* or a heavier weight of *EF WINDSOR Light Condensed* and it seems that Allen [simply liked it](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2011/apr/05/windsor-woody-allen-type) so much, that it became his signature:

> The story goes that Allen was looking for a typeface for Love and
>   Death (1975). At the time he ate breakfast in the same New Jersey
>   diner as Ed Benguiat, the great American typographer (and jazz
>   percussionist), who recommended Windsor. Allen liked it, and that was
>   that. Windsor became a signature of his films, along with old jazz
>   tunes, thick-framed specs, fast-paced dialogue and neurosis.

[This page](http://kitblog.com/2007/12/woody_allens_typography.html) provides a very good analysis of the subject and a complete list of his films (up to 2014 *Magic in the Moonlight*) with information whether the credits font comply to the EF WINDSOR style or not.